# Can't access label in content place holder in master page

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages, contentplaceholder

My master page contains this:

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <asp:Label ID="User" runat="server" Text="Welcome, " Visible="false"></asp:Label>
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

I'm trying to access the label like this:

```
Label welcomeLabel;
ContentPlaceHolder cPlaceHolder;            

cPlaceHolder = (ContentPlaceHolder)Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1");

if (cPlaceHolder != null)
{
    welcomeLabel = (Label)cPlaceHolder.FindControl("User");
    if (welcomeLabel != null)
    {
        welcomeLabel.Text = "Welcome, " + u.Name;
        welcomeLabel.Visible = true;
    }
 }
```

I've checked that ContentPlaceHolder1 is actually found and using HasControls() on it returns true but I can't seem to access the label.

Help me?

Comment: try finding this.Master.FindControl("User"); and see if it is coming or not

Comment: At which moment do you call your code?  Also, am i right that this code runs in the context of a page embedded in another contentplaceholder?  I can tell you that your code works here.

Comment: @platon - This code runs on page load. When I put a label with id=user in the actual page this code is being called on it works but my understanding of master pages is that I shouldn't have to do that.

Comment: @Jackass, sorry, I did not understand you.  Could you please upload a sample?

Answer (score 2):

I also having same prblem.

what i have done is

```
  MasterPage ctl00 = FindControl("ctl00") as MasterPage;
ContentPlaceHolder cplacehld = ctl00.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1") as ContentPlaceHolder;
                Label label1= cplacehld.FindControl("User") as Label;
```

Answer (score 0):

try with:

```
((Label)this.Page.Master.FindControl("User")).Text = "Welcome, " + u.Name;   
((Label)this.Page.Master.FindControl("User")).Visible = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue dogged me for about two hours until I realized that if I have a asp:Content tag on my page with the contentplaceholderID set to the ID for the contentplaceholder in the master page that I will never be able to access any controls in the contenplacholder.  The asp:Content page is always merged with the MasterPage content, even if the asp:Content tag is empty on your content page.  To provide for the default content, I moved my label outside of the contentplaceholder tag and set the visibility to false.  If I then dynamically determined that I didn't have any content for my asp:Content tag I would then just set the label visibility to true to display my default content.  Not exactly elegant, but it works.